# Bazel: defines in a header-only library

Tags: bazel

If I have a header-only library (Eigen in my case) like this:

```
cc_library(
    name = "eigen",
    hdrs = glob(
        ["Eigen/**"],
        exclude = [
            "Eigen/src/OrderingMethods/Amd.h",
            "Eigen/src/SparseCholesky/**",
            "Eigen/Eigen",
            "Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers",
            "Eigen/MetisSupport",
            "Eigen/Sparse",
            "Eigen/SparseCholesky",
            "Eigen/SparseLU",
        ],
    ),
    defines = [
        "EIGEN_MPL_ONLY",
        "EIGEN_NO_DEBUG",
        "EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE",
        "EIGEN_UNALIGNED_VECTORIZE=0",
        "EIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=32",
        "EIGEN_MAX_STATIC_ALIGN_BYTES=32",
        "EIGEN_NO_AUTOMATIC_RESIZING"
    ],
)
```

Are the defines observed at all, or do I have to manually add these defines to each dependend library?

additionally, say I have two libraries in my project that depend on Eigen, and I want to compile one with AVX512 and the other without. How can I hide the respective compiled eigen symbols from each other, so that it does not reuse the ones compiled with different defines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A target that depedens on `eigen` will also inherit the defines (e.g. `EIGEN_MPL_ONLY`).

See for details [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary.defines):

> Each string, ..., is
> prepended with -D and added to the compile command line to this
> target, as well as to every rule that depends on it

A can also setup a small testbed to check how defines work:

**WORKSPACE.bazel**

```
# Empty
```

**main/BUILD.bazel**

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = ["//my_header_only_lib:my_header_only_lib"]
)
```

**main/main.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Vector3<float> vec;
    vec.print();

    #ifdef FOO_BAR
            std::cout << "FOO_BAR is also known in main" << std::endl;
    #endif
}
```

**my_header_only_lib/BUILD.bazel**

```
package(
    default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "my_header_only_lib",
    hdrs = ["header.h"],
    includes=["."],
    defines = ["FOO_BAR"],
)
```

**my_header_only_lib/my_header_only_lib.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

template<typename ScalarType>
class Vector3 {
public:
    ScalarType x, y, z;

    void print() {
        #ifdef FOO_BAR
            std::cout << "FOO_BAR defined" << std::endl;
        #endif
    }
};
```

**Output**

```
FOO_BAR defined
FOO_BAR is also known in main
```

Comment: even though eigen has no srcs itself?

Comment: @user1282931 All defines are collected and handed over to the compiler